# Adding a new column by comparing values from multiple data frames and conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I wanted to add a new column in a data frame according to matching variables if there are, and other conditions if there aren't. When I used the `match` function, I realized inconsistencies between the data frames (literally messed it up - I know, indexing) and the main data frame has repeated observations whereas the observations in the second one are unique.

So here's the imitated data frames:

```
df = data.frame(kin1 = c("392", "392", "694", "615", "392", NA, "782"),
                anon = c("D1","D2","D3","D4", "D5","D6", "D7"))

df2 = data.frame(id = c("424","392", "615","429"),
                 rep = c("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4"))
```

What I wanted to do is to create a third column for the first data frame with these conditions:

- 1. If the variable in the `kin1` column in `df` matches with the
     variable `id` column in `df2` then the new column in the `df` should
     take the value in the `rep` column of `df2`.
- 2. If the variable in the `kin1` column in `df` is `NA`, then the new column in the `df` should be `NA` as well.
- 3. Finally, if both conditions aren't being met, then the new column in the `df` should
     take the value in the `anon` column of the same dataframe.

So my desired output should seem like:

```
desired.df
  kin1 anon new_id
1  392   D1     H2
2  392   D2     H2
3  694   D3     D3
4  615   D4     H3
5  392   D5     H2
6 <NA>   D6   <NA>
7  782   D7     D7
```

I have already tried nested for loops and it seems like it is working but my real data is massive so I really need something smarter and faster to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `dplyr::coalesce()`?

Comment: I am not trying to complete NAs from another data frame's column, in contrast, I am trying to keep NAs when there is but it's just one condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **dplyr** and **tidyr**

This example does use a nested `ifelse`. I had to step away for a second when I was about to answer and then came back and noticed `@r2evans` answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(kin1 = c("392", "392", "694", "615", "392", NA, "782"),
                anon = c("D1","D2","D3","D4", "D5","D6", "D7"))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c("424","392", "615","429"),
                 rep = c("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4"))

merge(df1,df2,by.x='kin1',by.y='id',sort=FALSE,incomparables='anon',all=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(new_id=ifelse(!is.na(rep),rep,ifelse(is.na(kin1),NA,anon))) %>%
  drop_na(anon) %>%
  select(,-3)
```

```
#  kin1 anon new_id
#1  392   D1     H2
#2  392   D2     H2
#3  392   D5     H2
#4  615   D4     H3
#5  694   D3     D3
#6 <NA>   D6   <NA>
#7  782   D7     D7
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked really fast and smoothly!

Answer (score 2):

## base R

```r
merge(df, df2, by.x = "kin1", by.y = "id", all.x = TRUE) |>
  transform(rep = ifelse(is.na(kin1), NA, ifelse(is.na(rep), anon, rep)))
#   kin1 anon  rep
# 1  392   D1   H2
# 2  392   D2   H2
# 3  392   D5   H2
# 4  615   D4   H3
# 5  694   D3   D3
# 6  782   D7   D7
# 7 <NA>   D6 <NA>
```

I'm generally not a fan of nested `ifelse` (of `ifelse` *in general*), but this works well enough.

## dplyr

We're able to take advantage of either `case_when` (as a replacement for nested `ifelse`) or `coalesce` here.

```r
left_join(df, df2, by = c(kin1 = "id")) |>
  mutate(rep = case_when(is.na(kin1) ~ NA, is.na(rep) ~ anon, TRUE ~ rep))
#   kin1 anon  rep
# 1  392   D1   H2
# 2  392   D2   H2
# 3  694   D3   D3
# 4  615   D4   H3
# 5  392   D5   H2
# 6 <NA>   D6 <NA>
# 7  782   D7   D7

left_join(df, df2, by = c(kin1 = "id")) |>
  mutate(rep = if_else(is.na(kin1), NA, coalesce(rep, anon)))
### same output
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Only R base solution worked with a flaw where it didn't put the input from the first data frame's `anon` column.

The others gave an error saying that "Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `rep = case_when(is.na(kin1) ~ NA, is.na(rep) ~ anon, TRUE ~ rep)`" and "Caused by error in `if_else()`: ! `false` must be a logical vector, not a character vector.", respectively.

I guess I missed a point when I'm imitating the data as an example here.

Comment: replace `~ NA` with `~ rep[NA]` or `~ NA_character_`, both should work. What version of `dplyr` are you running? My `packageVersion("dplyr")` is `1.1.4`.

Answer (score 2):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df);setDT(df2)
df[df2, new_id := i.rep, on = .(kin1 = id)][is.na(new_id) & !is.na(kin1), new_id := anon][]
#    kin1 anon new_id
# 1:  392   D1     H2
# 2:  392   D2     H2
# 3:  694   D3     D3
# 4:  615   D4     H3
# 5:  392   D5     H2
# 6: <NA>   D6   <NA>
# 7:  782   D7     D7
```